# Move SQL server install to new machine?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server, installation, migration

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 that was running SQL Server, until it had a unclean power down and now the operating system become corrupted. Before I struggle to resurrect the machine, I'd like to know if there is a way to move the SQL server installation to a new machine, without relying on backups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't move the SQL Server install.  (Or *really*, **really** shouldn't.)

You install SQL server fresh on a new machine and **move the databases**.

[Here's a rather long step-by-step article form Microsoft on how to move all the "stuff" from one SQL Server install to a SQL Server install on another machine](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314546).

It's too long to post here, but the section headers are:

> Step 1: How to move user databases
>
> Step 2: How to transfer logins and passwords
>
> Step 3: How to resolve orphaned users
>
> Step 4: How to move jobs, alerts, and operators
>
> Step 5: How to move DTS packages
>
> Step 6: Change the sp_configure settings to match the previous
>   computer

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the database files (mdf and ldf) then you can copy those to a new SQL Server and attach them.

Comment: Could you advise whether the service master key needs to be backup/restored on the destination server or does it automatically come suppose I restore the master database?